# Rider isn't setting my msbuild variable BuildingInsideVisualStudio

Tags: c#, msbuild, rider

My msbuild script is not executing according to plan.  For some reason, one of my variables isn't resolving to anything, but it's a standard variable.

In the log:

```
Task "ResolveNonMSBuildProjectOutput" skipped, due to false condition;
('$(BuildingInsideVisualStudio)'=='true' and '@(ProjectReferenceWithConfiguration)'!='') 
was evaluated as (''=='true' and ''!='').
```

Notice that the `$(BuildingInsideVisualStudio)` seems to resolve to an empty string.

In Rider (version 2017.3), I right-click the project -> properties -> under the Diagnostic section there is an option for properties.  In this view, are all the project variables, including BuildingInsideVisualStudio, which is set to True.

What do I need to look at to ensure Rider is setting this variable when I build from inside the IDE?

Edit: PS: I have also tried `BuildingByReSharper`, which also didn't work.  And, my co-workers using Rider are not having this issue.

Comment: That might be formatting for the log output.  I just searched my project script for that variable, and I didn't find it.

Comment: Is it .net core project?

Comment: What happens if you run it under Resharper build engine? :D

Comment: It worked using the Resharper Build engine!  Life saver!

Comment: So it did not work via disabled 'ReSharper Build'?

Comment: I believe there is still an issue here so have raised a bug for the Rider team: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RIDER-21855

Comment: ya, actually I have a bug reported with them as well about this, I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The workaround is using ReSharper's Build Engine, instead of MSBuild for those properties to be respected:

[image]